# Unclassifiable statement at 1 , Non-numeric character in statement label at 1

Tags: fortran, fortran77

i'm totally new to Fortran, and i want to write a test program using a `real*8` function called `NeQuick`, so i've written the following program :

```pascal
program test

implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)


aNe=NeQuick(400.0D0,45.0D0,15.0D0,10,1.929D2,15.0D0)
write(6,'(A,E12.5,A)')
& ' NeQuick electron density =',aNE,' m^-3'

call sleep(10)
end program
```

At the end when i compile it I have the following errors in each line of the little program : -Non-numeric character in statement label at 1  or
                 -Unclassifiable statement at 1

Can you guys please explain me what's wrong with my program ?

Comment: You should use code tags for source code ( for better readability).

Comment: Check at which columns you have your statements in the file and tell us that.

Answer (score 5):

The way this code is written tells me that it was intended to be fixed-form source. This requires that all of the code start in column 7, except for the & in the second line of the WRITE statement which should be in column 6.  Often when such code is pasted into an editor, the leading blanks are removed. If you do this, though, you will have to rename the source file to have a .f or .for file type so that the compiler knows it is fixed-form.

Another, perhaps easier solution is to put an & at the end of the first line of the WRITE - this will then make the source as you have it valid free-form.

For some perspective on this, please read [Source Form Just Wants to be Free](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/11/doctor-fortran-in-source-form-just-wants-to-be-free).